# Stop animation using slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, slidetoggle

I have a button `<button class="foo">Foo</button>` with an event handler attached to it that expands or collapses a block using `.slideToggle()`

```
$('.foo').on('click', function () {
  const fooBlock = $(this).next();
  fooBlock.slideToggle(() => {
    fooBlock.toggleClass('hidden');
  });
```

If a user clicks the button when an animation is in transition then the click is queued. How do I stop the animation if the user clicks the button while the animation is already executing?

Comment: Alternatively, have a boolean inTransition and check in the click handler if there's already a transition happening or not. No need to remove/readd handlers, that will only slow down the page compared to leaving the handler there and just not executing it sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better solution is to just use `stop(true)` to clear the queue on successive clicks. This means the UI is still responsive to user input during the animation and also prevents the animations building up. Try this:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
  const fooBlock = $(this).next();
  fooBlock.stop(true).slideToggle(() => {
    fooBlock.toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```